Socket.io en servidor nodejs clusterizado
Necesito crear un sistema que cuando un usuario crea una publicación, me permita notificar a los usuarios suscriptos a él, que dicho usuario creo una publicación.
Ya tengo implementada la autenticación para agregar el uid (user id) del usuario al socketServer; el detalle es que mi servidor está clusterizado y cada worker tiene su propio servidor Io, entonces cuando se envía una notificación esa notificación llega solo al socket Io del usuario que creo la publicación y si los demás usuarios no están conectados al mismo socket Io entonces pues no reciben la notificación.
Es la primera vez intento implementar algo así y según la información que estuve leyendo lo que necesito en un adaptador que conecte o emita a todos los sockets la notificación.
Estuve probando hacerlo con redis, mongo db y @socket.io/cluster-adapter, nada me está funcionando.
¿Como se supone que se hace esto? ¿Hay alguna forma estándar de hacer esto?
Se supone que debería ser algo de uso regular pero no logro echar a andar esto.
Cualquier ayuda o pista al menos me sería muy útil.

La única vez que me enfrenté a un problema similar con microservicios usé MQTT para enviar mensajes. Básicamente un servicio de eventos... un emisor que envía los datos pertinentes a todos los clientes que estén a la escucha y cada uno decide si necesita consumir el mensaje o no.

Si, MQTT es liviano, sencillo y fácil de usar.
